# Android - BottomNavigationMenu and listView in a Linear Layout

Tags: android, listview, bottomnavigationview

I have a strange problem with my BottomNavigationBar

The situations is this:
I have an activity that contains 
 - A little Fragment for showing Debts and Credits and it works 
 - A listView with all my expenditures and it works as well
 - A bottomNavigationMenuBar that work partially, indeed it is not anchored to the bottom of my activity but if stay at the bottom of the ListView untill the ListView occupy all the space on the display

I attach some screen to explain better
[image: no good behaviour, it must stay at the bottom]
no good behaviour, it must stay at the bottom

[image]
ListView is bigger than the screen and it works good

Here is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tab_bck"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearVerticalLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/tab_bck" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/expenseToolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:subtitleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                /></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="it.polito.mad17.viral.sliceapp.Fragment_of_money"
                />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/tab_bck"
                android:longClickable="true"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_bar_menu"
                design:itemIconTint="#16a085"
                design:itemTextColor="#16a085"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your BottomBar outside the Linear Layout. Like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tab_bck"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearVerticalLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/tab_bck" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/expenseToolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:subtitleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                /></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="it.polito.mad17.viral.sliceapp.Fragment_of_money"
                />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/tab_bck"
                android:longClickable="true"
                />
</LinearLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_bar_menu"
                design:itemIconTint="#16a085"
                design:itemTextColor="#16a085"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This should work for you

Comment: it works at my side. check it then let me know it work or not@Kalos92

Comment: works partially, but the problem is: when the ListView is occpuying all the screen the last visible item goes under the BottomNavigationBar

Comment: make bottom bar height fix like `60dp`. then in Linear layout tag add margin bottom `60dp`. Like this:   `android:layout_marginBottom="60dp`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving LinearVerticalLayout's android:layout_height="match_parent", may be it'll work